# access the last element of the UIPageViewController

Tags: swift

How do I access the last item of a UIPageViewController so I can set self as its delegate?

```
self.present(wizard, animated: true, completion: {
    let lastVC = wizard.viewControllers?.last as! thirdPageController
    lastVC.delegate = self        
})
```

I think the third item wasn't loaded yet so `.last` returns the wrong page (the first one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Swift 5**

- Create your own UIPageViewController:

```
class MyPageViewController: UIPageViewController {

  private lazy var _viewControllers = [UIViewController]()

  public var lastViewController: UIViewController? {
    return _viewControllers.last
  }

  override func setViewControllers(_ viewControllers: [UIViewController]?, direction: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection, animated: Bool, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
    super.setViewControllers([viewController], direction: direction, animated: animated, completion: completion)

    _viewControllers.removeAll()
    _viewControllers.append(viewControllers)
  }

}
```

**Class usage:**

```
let myPageViewController = MyPageViewController()

myPageViewController.lastViewController // This is an optional value
```

**Finally you should change the class of** `wizard` `UIPageViewController` **to** `MyPageViewController`

**Then you can use this new class like:**

```
self.present(wizard, animated: true, completion: {

    if let lastViewController = wizard.lastViewController as? thirdPageController {
        lastViewController.delegate = self
    }
})
```